# Highchart org chart type error with ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts, orgchart

Implementing Highcharts organisation chart with ionic application using https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart  resulted in the following error

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts:29:11 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"area" | "map" | "line" | "polygon" | "item" | "abands" | "ad" | "ao" | "apo" | "arearange" | "areaspline" | "areasplinerange" | "aroon" | "aroonoscillator" | "atr" | "bar" | "bb" | ... 80 more ... | "zigzag"'.
[ng] 29           type: 'organization',
[ng]              ~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts:189657:5
[ng]     189657     type: "abands";
[ng]                ~~~~
[ng]     The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions | SeriesAoOptions | SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions | SeriesArearangeOptions | SeriesAreasplineOptions | SeriesAreasplinerangeOptions | ... 89 more ... | SeriesZigzagOptions'
[ng]
```

I included the required scripts in index.html file.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/organization.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';
import highcharts from "highcharts/modules/organization";
highcharts(HighCharts);
```

How do I fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import it like that:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as Sankey from "highcharts/modules/sankey";
import * as Organization from "highcharts/modules/organization";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

Sankey(Highcharts);
Organization(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
```

**Angular Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-qdq4f

Comment: I noticed this error now   [ng] ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts:8:1 - error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("/Users/durgaprasad/Desktop/ionic/myApp1/node_modules/highcharts/modules/sankey")' has no compatible call signatures.
[ng] 8 Sankey(Highcharts);
[ng]   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: src/app/home/home.page.ts:9:1 - error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("/Users/durgaprasad/Desktop/ionic/myApp1/node_modules/highcharts/modules/organization")' has no compatible call signatures.
[ng] 9 Organization(Highcharts);
[ng]   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: What version of Highcharts do you use? Could you reproduce your app in an online code editor like codesandbox?

Comment: I push the code to  https://github.com/prasadrajacse/myApp1                                      On running ionic serve, I see the same error as mentioned in the question. Thanks

Comment: As I can see you're not using `highcharts-angular` wrapper. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular. Try to use it and check if this issue still exists (it should not). An example is in my answer above `highcharts-angular`.

Comment: I am creating an ionic project, Can I use the same wrapper ?

Comment: Ionic is built on top of Angular so it should work.